# Apache access.log sort ip hits and custom output the results

Tags: apache, sorting, awk, uniq

I've been trying to sort and custom print the results from an apache.log file.
The situation is that I would like to see the results as:

The output should represent total hits per month sorted by month

The output should look like:

```
Nov 2017 hits count - 12512

Dec 2017 hits count - 10087

Jan 2018 hits count - 12561
```

Here is part of the access.log for reference:

```
91.244.19.43 - - [12/Dec/2015:19:02:36 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 239 "http://localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.143 Safari/537.36" "-"
91.244.19.43 - - [12/Dec/2015:19:02:36 +0100] "GET /images/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1963 "http://localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.143 Safari/537.36" "-"
91.244.19.46 - - [12/Dec/2015:19:02:36 +0100] "GET /template/ HTTP/1.1" 200 10004 "http://localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.143 Safari/537.36" "-"
91.244.19.43 - - [12/Dec/2015:19:02:36 +0100] "GET /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 200 1801 "http://localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.143 Safari/537.36" "-"
193.47.55.21 - - [12/Dec/2015:19:02:36 +0100] "GET /wp-admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1457 "http://localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.143 Safari/537.36" "-"
193.47.55.21 - - [12/Dec/2015:19:02:36 +0100] "GET /template/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3465 "http://localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.143 Safari/537.36" "-"
11.114.21.37 - - [12/Dec/2015:19:02:36 +0100] "GET /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 200 4890 "http://localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.143 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

I came up with something like this:

```
cat access.log |sort -k1n|awk '{print $4}'|cut -d: -f1|cut -d/ -f2-3|sed 's/\[//g'|tr '/' ' '|sort -k2n -k1M
```

It does the job, printing the year/month and the hit count, but I need the output to be as the example above. In other words, I want to put the "hits counts" between the time frame and the number value of the actual hits count. Any idea how I can do that?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
cat access.log | awk '{ print substr($4,5,3),substr($4,9,4) }' | \
 sort -k1  | \
 uniq -c | \
 gawk '{ print $2,$3,"hits count - ",$1}'
```

First print month and year,

then sort (not really needed),

then count the `uniq` lines,

then print `month`,`year`,`"hits count -"`, and the number counted.

Comment: Thank you. Works like a charm. Is it possible to print the uniq ip hit counts instead of the total number of hits?

Comment: Yes, of course this possible. You need to learn the basics of (g)awk, and than you can change this commands yourself.  SO (stackoverflow) is not a website where people write code for you.....

Comment: Probably get rid of the [useless `cat`.](/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat)